# Не работает std::thread

Tags: многопоточность, clang++

Компилирую clang++
строчка из-за которой возникает ошибка: `std::thread t = std::thread([&] () { recvdata(ClientSocket); });`

Полный вывод компилятора:

```
In file included from server.cpp:18:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\thread:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\memory:14:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\xmemory:727:76: error:
      call to deleted constructor of 'std::thread'
  727 |   ...volatile void*>(_Ptr))) _Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
      |                              ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector:798:27: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread>>::construct<std::thread,
      const std::thread &>' requested here
  798 |             _Alty_traits::construct(_Getal(), _Unfancy(_Mylast), _STD forward<_...
      |                           ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector:780:20: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::thread>::_Emplace_back_with_unused_capacity<const std::thread  
      &>' requested here
  780 |             return _Emplace_back_with_unused_capacity(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
      |                    ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector:871:9: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::thread>::_Emplace_one_at_back<const std::thread &>' requested  
      here
  871 |         _Emplace_one_at_back(_Val);
      |         ^
server.cpp:157:17: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::vector<std::thread>::push_back' requested here
  157 |         threads.push_back(t);
      |                 ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\thread:113:5: note:
      'thread' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  113 |     thread(const thread&)            = delete;
      |     ^
In file included from server.cpp:19:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector:834:23: error:
      no matching member function for call to 'construct'
  834 |         _Alty_traits::construct(_Al, _Unfancy(_Newvec + _Whereoff), _STD forwar...
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector:783:17: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::thread>::_Emplace_reallocate<const std::thread &>' requested   
      here
  783 |         return *_Emplace_reallocate(_Mylast, _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);   
      |                 ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vector:871:9: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::thread>::_Emplace_one_at_back<const std::thread &>' requested  
      here
  871 |         _Emplace_one_at_back(_Val);
      |         ^
server.cpp:157:17: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::vector<std::thread>::push_back' requested here
  157 |         threads.push_back(t);
      |                 ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\xmemory:723:30: note:
      candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Objty = std::thread,     
      _Types = <const std::thread &>]
  723 |     static _CONSTEXPR20 void construct(_Alloc&, _Objty* const _Ptr, _Types&&.....
      |                              ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Полностью код приведите. Ошибка же в попытке скопировать объект потока в вектор.

Comment: Просто функцию передавать в создаваемый thread религия не позволяет?